# Unable to perform POST operation in React with fetch

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-router, reactstrap

I am attempting to perform POST request using ReactJS and update in a Mongo-database using Spring-boot. During the compilation of the code I did not get any errors, yet when trying to perform a POST operation I do not get an output. When I refresh the page I get an entry in the database with an ID but with no name.

This is the code for the react application:

```
async handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const {item} = this.state;

    await fetch(`/person/new`, {
      method : 'POST',
      headers : {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body : JSON.stringify({item}),
    });
    
    this.props.history.push("/change");
  }
```

The code for POST in Spring-boot is :

```
public Integer Counter(){
    List<Person> p = pr.findAll();
    c = 1;
    while(pr.existsById(c)) {
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}

@PostMapping("/new")
public void insertPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
    Integer id = Counter();
    String name = person.getName();
    pr.save(new Person(id,name));
    c++;
}
```

This is my site looks when the code is executed ↓

[How my site looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgHVw.png)

Please help me with this.

PS: DELETE operation is working though.

Comment: first check your network tab, so make sure the frontend sends the correct format of data to backend.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of how you call this function. I'd suggest invoking it like so: `onClick = { async (e) => await { this.handleSubmit(e); } }`